# neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: .net, postgresql, visual-studio-2017, npgsql, .net-framework-version

Can anyone help me, I'm working on .NET Framework version 4.5.
I'm trying to add the data connection of PostgreSQL but this message came out.

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I tried different version but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue that is already reported on github](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2677). Upvote the issue and look for fixes.