# MSBuild 16.0 not finding its own dependent assemblies when loaded through MSBuildLocator

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to run MSBuild programmatically from a C# DLL (which will ultimately be loaded from PowerShell), and as a first step from a command-line application. I have used Microsoft.Build.Locator as recommended (or so I reckon) by installing its NuGet package to my project, and adding the following references to my test project:

```xml
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9dff12846e04bfbd, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Build.Locator.1.2.6\lib\net46\Microsoft.Build.Locator.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

The project targets .NET Framework 4.8, and the source code is as follows:

```cs
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace nrm_testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
            DoStuff();
        }
        
        static void DoStuff()
        {
            using (var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection())
            {
                var buildParameters = new BuildParameters
                {
                    MaxNodeCount = 1 // https://stackoverflow.com/q/62658963/3233393
                };
                
                var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(
                    @"path\to\a\project.vcxproj",
                    new Dictionary<string, string>(),
                    null,
                    new string[0],
                    null
                );

                var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequestData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Upon entering the `using` block, I receive the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

The Modules window shows that MSBL did successfully locate my VS2019 installation:

```
Microsoft.Build.dll           16.07.0.37604 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.dll
Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll 16.07.0.37604 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll
Microsoft.Build.Locator.dll   1.02.6.49918  C:\dev\nrm3-tests\nrm\nrm-testing\.out\AnyCPU-Debug\Microsoft.Build.Locator.dll
```

`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` is indeed present besides the located MSBuild assemblies, in version 4.0.6.0 (according to DotPeek).

What could be causing this error, and how could I fix it?

---

My attempts so far:

- I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60221078/3233393), but the [linked GitHub issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2677) is still open and I'm unsure whether it's the same problem.
- I have managed to get a binding redirection working, but I don't think I can use them from within a DLL, so that's a dead end.
- Adding the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` NuGet package to the project (and verifying that it is indeed copied alongside the project's executable) does nothing (thanks magicandre1981 for the suggestion).
- Switching from packages.config to PackageReference (as suggested by Perry Qian), with no change in behaviour.

Comment: add System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe package directly to project

Comment: @magicandre1981 I just tried -- alas, no change whatsoever.

Comment: in [app.config add assemblyBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#manually-editing-the-app-config-file) entries for System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Comment: @magicandre1981 that works in my test application, however manually binding the dependencies of a dynamically-located assembly feels like a huge hack. The real problem, though, is that libraries cannot declare binding redirects... I will look into a workaround I found elsewhere based on overriding one of the assembly loader's callbacks.

Comment: this is no hack, this is normal, VS does this on its own when adding packages

Comment: you can also add [AutoGenerateBindingRedirects and GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46120907/1466046) to csproj

Comment: @magicandre1981 usually yes, but the whole point of MSBuildLocator is to just use the existing MSBuild installation. Distributing a copy of the dependencies from every MSBuild version because they can't find their own pieces sounds pretty fishy to me.

Comment: as you already noticed, there is an open bug on this. Wait until it is fixed.

Comment: @Quentin, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling with different ideas, I ended up writing this workaround based on [manual assembly resolution](https://blog.slaks.net/2013-12-25/redirecting-assembly-loads-at-runtime).

`RegisterMSBuildAssemblyPath` detects when `Microsoft.Build.dll` gets loaded, and memorizes its directory. Upon subsequent assembly load failures, `RedirectMSBuildAssemblies` checks if the missing assembly exists inside that path, and loads it if it does.

```
class Program
{
    private static string MSBuildAssemblyDir;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();

        Thread.GetDomain().AssemblyLoad += RegisterMSBuildAssemblyPath;
        Thread.GetDomain().AssemblyResolve += RedirectMSBuildAssemblies;

        DoStuff();
    }

    private static void RegisterMSBuildAssemblyPath(object sender, AssemblyLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        var assemblyPath = args.LoadedAssembly.Location;

        if (Path.GetFileName(assemblyPath) == "Microsoft.Build.dll")
            MSBuildAssemblyDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath);
    }

    private static Assembly RedirectMSBuildAssemblies(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (MSBuildAssemblyDir == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            var assemblyFilename = $"{args.Name.Split(',')[0]}.dll";
            var potentialAssemblyPath = Path.Combine(MSBuildAssemblyDir, assemblyFilename);

            return Assembly.LoadFrom(potentialAssemblyPath);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static void DoStuff()
    {
        // Same as before
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure there are (many) corner cases that will make this fail, but it will do for now.

Comment: Since you have a workaround, I suggest you could mark your own answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is an real issue for a long time for [packages.config nuget management format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config). And **Microsoft's** recommended solution for this problem is to add a bindingRedirect.

**Usually**, you can use this node in `xxx.csproj` file to automatically generate bindingredirect.

**However**, for some specific dlls, this node may not work due to serveral reasons. And it is still an issue on the current `packages.config nuget management format` as your said.

**Suggestion**

**As a suggestion**, you could use the [new PackageReference nuget manage format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) instead since **VS2017**. This format is simple, convenient and efficient.

**Also**, when you use this format, first, you should make a backup of your project.

Just right-click on the `packages.config` file-->click `Migrate packages.config to PackageReference`.

**Besides**, I have also reported [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1208079/msbuild-160-not-finding-its-own-dependent-assembli.html) on DC Forum and I hope the team will provide a better suggestion.

Comment: No luck with `PackageReference` either... I have managed to make the binding redirect work on my test application, but that doesn't help with my end goal which has to be a library. I have since found a somewhat hacky workaround based on manually loading unresolved assemblies from MSBuild's directory, which I'll document in an answer as soon as I get the time.